# Bitwise math operations in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to understand a [function](https://github.com/shurans/sscnet/blob/c8699e18263f54083bb837b8fa67570b5710b050/caffe_code/caffe3d_suncg/src/caffe/layers/suncg_fusion.hpp#L40-L46) that reads and transforms depth data stored as 16-bit png file.

First they load the file into a opencv Mat of type `CV_16UC1`

```
cv::Mat depth_image = cv::imread(filename.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
```

Then they assign

```
unsigned short * depth_raw = new unsigned short[frame_height * frame_width];
for (int i = 0; i < frame_height * frame_width; ++i) {
  depth_raw[i] = ((((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 1]) << 8) + ((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 0]));
  depth_raw[i] = (depth_raw[i] << 13 | depth_raw[i] >> 3);
  depth_data[i] = float((float)depth_raw[i] / 1000.0f);
}
```

Now I know that the "<<" operator in C++ is something like a bit shift, meaning `5 << 1` corresponds to the following bit-shift: "00000101" (which is 5 in binary) -> "00001010" (which is 10 in binary). So apparantly one can do multiplications  and divisions by 2^n using "<< n" or ">> n".

Still I find it hard to understand the transformation above. Here is an example with numbers (applying `cout` to every step) for the above transformation:

```
depth_image.data[i] = 192
depth_image.data[2*i+1] = 47
depth_image.data[2*i+0] = 192
(((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 1]) << 8) = 12032
((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 0]) = 192
depth_raw[i] = 12224
depth_raw[i] << 13 = 0
depth_raw[i] >> 3 = 191
depth_raw[i] << 13 | depth_raw[i] >> 3 = 191
depth_data[i] = 1.528
```

What is really weird is the last line: It seems like the conversion from `unsigned short` to `float` is converting the number 191 into 1528 ???

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Edit:
I found some Matlab code that shows how the authors saved the depth image previously:

```
% resave depth map with bit shifting
depthRaw = double(imread(filename))/1000;
saveDepth (depthRaw,newFilename);

function saveDepth (depth,filename)
    depth(isnan(depth)) =0;
    depth =single(depth)*1000;
    depthVis = uint16(depth);
    depthVis = bitor(bitshift(depthVis,3), bitshift(depthVis,3-16));
    imwrite(depthVis,filename);
end
```

So it looks like a weird saving...

Edit2:
Reply from the authors:
"The depth map is saved in a way that it shifts 3 bits to make the depth in PNG format more pleasing to human eyes. Therefore we need to shift it back during file reading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no common norm, how data is stored. Therefore it may be neccessary to convert from little to big endian or the other way around. To understand endianess have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

```
depth_raw[i] = ((((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 1]) << 8) + ((unsigned short)depth_image.data[i * 2 + 0]));
```

This statement is a convertion of endianess. the first byte is cast to unsigned short (from 8 to 16 bit) and then shifted right and then the second byte is added at the lower end. It basically swaps two bytes and converts it to an unsigned int.

```
depth_raw[i] = (depth_raw[i] << 13 | depth_raw[i] >> 3);
depth_data[i] = float((float)depth_raw[i] / 1000.0f);
```

After the convertion of endianess, the data has to be interpreted. The only way to be sure what the authors inteded to do here is to have a look at the documentation of the depth map. The first line moves the 3 least significant bits to the front and the others down. I have no idea, why this is done. I think the division by 1000 after that is only to correct for units (maybe m in mm or km in m), or it some kind of fixed point semantic. (represantion of rational number in interger data type).

Comment: Thanks for the strong, well-informed answer. I already contacted the authors but no reply so far. I will post the solution once I found the answer...